# build boost c++ 1.48.0 with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have been trying to build c++ boost to work with qt creator but until now all what i get is undefined reference to different things things so here is what I did so far:-

1. I build c++ boost by running bootstrap.bat then bjam
2. I include the path in my qt creator .pro project

like this

```
QT += core gui

TARGET = Heap
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost\boost_1_48_0

LIBS += -L"C:/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib"

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    clss.h \
    inputstream.h \
    outputstream.h \
    myexception.h \
    heaptest.h \
    comparable.h \
    heap.h

FORMS    +=
```

here is my sample code I am testing on

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and here is the compilation error I get

```
debug/main.o: In function `cpp_regex_traits_char_layer':
C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:366: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/regex_raw_buffer.hpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::resize(unsigned int)'
debug/main.o: In function `save_state_init':
C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
debug/main.o: In function `~save_state_init':
C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:115: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:206: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:1117: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/pattern_except.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:219: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:219: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:219: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:798: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:799: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:799: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:799: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:880: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:881: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:881: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:881: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:945: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:946: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:946: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:946: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1148: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1149: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1149: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1149: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:213: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:442: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:444: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:321: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::insert(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:633: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::lookup_default_collate_name(std::string const&)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:675: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:690: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1059: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1062: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
debug/main.o:C:\Users\Aamer\Desktop\Heap-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0__4_8_0__Debug/../../../../boost/boost_1_48_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1062: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug/Heap.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
16:05:31: The process "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.4.0\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project Heap (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

How can I get this to build?

Comment: Boost.Regex requires a compiled library, which is missing from your Qt project settings. A minute of searching the internet should show you how to add the dependency to the project.

Comment: putting dependencies in the .pro file was one of my trials with no good too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `LIBS += -L"C:/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib"` line to:

```
LIBS += -L"C:/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib" -lboost_regex
```

(replace `boost_regex` with the actual name of the built library (which will probably be something like `boost_regex-mgw44-mt-1_48`))

Comment: I tried putting "-llibboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_48"  then             "-llibboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib"  but same error happened

Comment: Just `-lboost_regex` should do.

Comment: @user976749: It looks like you have built boost with the MSVC toolchain. QT uses the MinGW toolchain, which is not binary compatible with MSVC. You need to build boost with the MinGW which comes with QT (use the `toolset=gcc` argument for `b2`).

Comment: thanks for your help i build it using gcc and every thing works great.but I have one last question, do I have to add the dependencies every time in .pro project isn't there a way can make qt creator detect them by itself ?!! thanks again for your help

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781494/how-do-a-specify-a-library-file-dependency-for-qmake-in-qt

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288292/qmake-project-dependencies-linked-libraries