# Link dependency library with qmake

Tags: c++, qmake

I have a big qt project but it is composed of a main application, APIs and plugins

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += app api plugins updater

api.subdir = api
app.subdir = app
app.depends = api
plugins.subdir = plugins
plugins.depends = api
```

APIs are static libs. So, i want link automatically APIs with main app and plugins.

For example, i need to do:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/lib -lapi
```

But it's ugly and i can't share this. I want to qmake do it dynamically.

How can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/781494/3098505

Comment: @chrisb2244 I think it's more a duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417776/how-to-use-qmakes-subdirs-template) but I agree it's a duplicate